# Не работает выпадающий список yii2

Tags: php, yii2, select

_form.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Groups;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
?>

<div class="users-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); 
    $groups = Groups::find()->all();
    $items = ArrayHelper::map($groups,'id','name');
    $options = [
        $model->id => ['selected' => true],
    ]
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model,'id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model,'login')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model,'password')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model,'email')->textInput() ?>

    <?php $form->field($model,'group_id')->dropDownList($items,$options) ?>

    <?php //echo HTML::dropDownList('group_id',null,$items) ?>
    <?php //echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'group_id',$items,$options) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

model/users.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'login','password','email'], 'required'],
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            ['email','email'],
            [['id'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

}
```

UsersController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Users();
        $model->created_at=date('Y-m-d');
        $model->update_at=date('Y-m-d');

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Уже перепробовал разные методы, ничего не работает
`<?php $form->field($model,'group_id')->dropDownList($items,$options) ?>` - тупо не срабатывает
activeDropDownList и DropDownList генерирует HTML код:

```
 <select name="group_id">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Moder</option>
    <option value="3">User</option>
   </select>
```

но когда я нажимаю кнопку, и форма отправляет данные, почему то сами данные не добавляются в таблицу. Я в таблице установил group_id NULL и вижу что все поля отправляют данные, кроме списка.

Comment: И когда я хочу обновить какие то данные в какой либо записи, я могу изменить любое поле, кроме group_id

Comment: В модель надо в правила добавить поле `group_id`, иначе это поле игнорируется.